# « Être » ou « être de »?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

> Il est à noter que la quantité maximale autorisée est de 48 fioles.

> Il est à noter que la quantité maximale autorisée est 48 fioles.

Il est à noter que le nombre maximal de fioles autorisé est de 48.

Il est à noter que le nombre maximal de fioles autorisé est 48.

Comment: « Être » ou « ne pas être de »? ;-)

Comment: Telle est la question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forme générale considérée est « le/la/un/…nombre/prix/quantité/impot/… est (de) < nombre > < unité > … ». Dans certains cas cette préposition persiste à l'exclusion quasi complète des cas de non emploi. Une recherche en profondeur n'est évidemment pas possible.  Il semble cependant qu'il existe une tendance à ne pas utiliser « de ». Quelques données sont réunies ci-dessous et elles semblent aller dans le sens d'une confirmation.

**I-a**

[1897 le droit d'inscription est 25 francs](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dispositions_r%C3%A9glementaires_programmes/gXxBAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22est+25+francs%22&dq=%22est+25+francs%22&printsec=frontcover)
[1926 dont la cotisation annuelle est 25 francs](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Bulletin_mensuel/GQcVAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22est+25+francs%22&dq=%22est+25+francs%22&printsec=frontcover)
[1929 La somme principale qui est déterminée est 25 francs](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Causes_c%C3%A9l%C3%A8bres_du_droit_des_gens/bnA3AAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22est+25+francs%22&dq=%22est+25+francs%22&printsec=frontcover)
[1980 c'est la quantité demandée si le prix est 25 francs le kilo ;](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_m%C3%A9canismes_de_l_%C3%A9conomie_moderne/5NgeAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22est+25+francs%22&dq=%22est+25+francs%22&printsec=frontcover)

[1861 Le droit sur l'alun est de 25 francs par 100 kilogrammes ( loi du 7 juin 1820 ) . Le prix est de 25 francs.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Enqu%C3%AAte_Trait%C3%A9_de_commerce_avec_l_Angl/Y392dUrDBpcC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22est+de+25+francs%22&pg=PA460&printsec=frontcover)
[1894  lorsque le cours moyen français est de 25 francs ;](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Comptes_rendus_des_travaux_de_la_Soci%C3%A9t/z28jAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22est+de+25+francs%22&pg=PA288&printsec=frontcover)
[1910 que le legs particulier fait à Emile et Edouard Gauthier est de 25 francs ;](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Recueil_de_la_Gazette_des_tribunaux/zOEqAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22est+de+25+francs%22&dq=%22est+de+25+francs%22&printsec=frontcover)

**I-b**

[nombreux exemples de « prix est X francs »](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Recueil_de_la_Gazette_des_tribunaux/zOEqAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22est+de+25+francs%22&dq=%22est+de+25+francs%22&printsec=frontcover)  (*On trouve rarement  cette construction de nos jours, alors qu'elle est courante au 19<sup>e</sup>.*)

[nombreux exemples de « nombre est de X](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22le%20nombre%20est%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) (*Un examen montre que de nos jours cette construction n'est pratiquement pas utilisée ; on la trouve couramment au 19<sup>e</sup>.*)

**I-c**

[prix est cent francs,**prix est de cent francs**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prix+est+cent+francs%2Cprix+est+de+cent+francs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprix%20est%20de%20cent%20francs%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cprix%20est%20de%20cent%20francs%3B%2Cc0) (*La construction sans « de » n'existe pas*)
[prix est 100t francs,**prix est de 100 francs**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prix+est+100+francs%2Cprix+est+de+100+francs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprix%20est%20de%20100%20francs%3B%2Cc0) (*La construction sans « de » n'existe pas*)

**II**

Ni l'une ni l'autre des deux possibilités de base n'est incorrecte, et la seconde semble préférable, vu la tendance qui dans certain cas a abouti à la disparition ou raréfaction de l'usage de « de ». Il n'y a aucun problème dans le déplacement du nom exprimant l'unité ; c'est une question de choix qui dépend de qui rédige la phrase.

Comment: try googling this: "le nombre maximum était de" or "le montant minimum était de". Il me semble que dans des locutions pareilles on préfère le de.