# Pourquoi y a-t-il un « de » dans la phrase « les tarifs sont de vingt, trente, et cinquante-cinq euros »

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, prépositions

Est-ce que je puis dire  « les tarifs sont vingt, trente, et cinquante-cinq euros », sans « de » ? Merci!

Comment: Et aussi [« Être » ou « être de »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/49658/358)

Answer (score 2):

Bien que correct, on n'utilise pas vraiment 'le tarif est vingt euros' qui reste assez vague (lequel ? quand ? négociable ?)
Quand on parle argent, on a intérêt à être plus ferme :
Le tarif, ***c'est*** vingt euros
Le tarif est ***de*** vingt euros.
(Ici, maintenant)

Answer (score 2):

Ça se comprend, mais ce n'est pas vraiment courant d'omettre le "de".

La construction habituelle pour indiquer la mesure de quelque chose combine *substantif* + de + *nombre*, par exemple :

- le billet a un prix de 20 euros / le prix du billet est de 20 euros
- la chambre a une longueur de 4 mètres / la longueur de la chambre est de 4 mètres
- le délai a une durée de 2 mois / la durée du délai est de 2 mois
- le bagage a un poids de 10 kg / le poids du bagage est de 10 kg